# Сделать из массива объектов массив массивов с уникальными значениями (объекты) на js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив объектов такого плана (для примера такой простенький):

```
let array = [
    { name: '1' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '4' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '3' },
    { name: '1' },
];
```

И на выходе нужно получить массив массивов такого плана:

```
result = [
    [{ name: '1' }, { name: '1' }],
    [{ name: '2' }, { name: '2' }],
    [{ name: '3' }],
    [{ name: '4' }]
];
```

То есть для одинаковых объектов (полная копия) создавать новый массив и туда их пушить.

С числами такое работает вот так у меня:

```
let result = [];
 let array = [4,1,3,3,2,4];
 array. forEach(function (a) {
    a in this || result.push(this[a] = [])
    this[a].push(a);
}, Object.create(null)); // [[4, 4], [1], [3, 3], [2]]
```

А вот с объектами не получается их вот так сгруппировать.
Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Группируем по ключу `key`. Смотрим есть ли объект с таким ключем в массиве и делаем вывод: либо добавить по индексу, либо в конец.

```js
let array = [
    { name: '1' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '4' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '3' },
    { name: '1' },
];

const key = 'name';

console.log(
  array.reduce((a,c) => {
    const idx = a.findIndex(e => e.length > 0 && e[0][key] === c[key]);
    return idx !== -1 ? (a[idx].push(c), a) : (a.push([c]), a);
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: ....пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если набор ключей непредсказуем, но объекты совместимы с JSON, можно так:

```js
let array = [
    { name: '1' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '4' },
    { name: '2' },
    { name: '3' },
    { name: '1' },
];

const result = Object.values(array.reduce(
  (acc, item) => {
    const id = JSON.stringify(item);
    acc[id] ??= [];
    acc[id].push(item);
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
    { name: "1" },
    { name: "2" },
    { name: "4" },
    { name: "2" },
    { name: "3" },
    { name: "1" },
];
let result = [];

array.forEach(function (obj) {
    const name = obj.name;
    name in this || result.push((this[name] = []));
    this[name].push(obj);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].